# abstract class <T> - getClass type

Tags: java, class, ejb, abstract, typed

I have abstract class like with some getting data method:

```
public abstract class BaseBean<T extends Object> 
{
...
  object = entityManager.find( ???, id);
...
}
```

My entity bean looks like:

```
public class InvoiceBean extends BaseBean<Invoice>
{ }
```

How I get class type [???]   (ex. Invoice) in abstract class? I need to use it in find method

Comment: Which language, and which version of its standard? Please tag your question with a language specific tag, and **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: Java6, Java7, Java8?

Comment: Don't comment your question, but **edit** it to improve it...